# JsonConvert returns null for List<object>

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize a List of objects, the serialize method returns null. The method is a copy of a different (working) method - I am not sure what the cause could be.  I have tried a few variations on having/omitting JsonProperty etc.  Having/not having getters and setters.

Using version 8.0.2 of the Newtonsoft.Json package (installed using nuget package manager, and Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 10.

...
using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
public class PharmacyProDrug
{
    [JsonProperty("DrugId")] public long DrugId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("GenericName")] public string GenericName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("DrugForm")] public string DrugForm { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TradeProductPack")] public ulong? TradeProductPack { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CPINumber")] public long? CPINumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TradeName")] public string TradeName { get; set; }

    public PharmacyProDrug()
    {

    }
    ....
}

.....

var pharmacyProDrugs = pharmacyProImporter.getDrugs(); // defined as public List<PharmacyProDrug> getDrugs()
if (pharmacyProDrugs.Count > 0) // Count = 9468
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pharmacyProDrugs,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    // returns "null"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Tested your class with a list, it works as expected, you have an error anywhere else. Arte you sure it's a List<PharmacyProDrug> what you're returning?

Comment: @Gusman Yes, quite sure.  var pharmacyProDrugList = new List<PharmacyProDrug>(); .... return pharmacyProDrugList;

Comment: Well, then recheck all, I copied your class, created a list, added 100 elements and serialized it and it worked without a problem...

Comment: I just tested this as well with no issues but I am just using a small amount of your objects as a test. I see in your image that there are 9468, this may be an issue with your jsonMaxLengthProperty, although you should get that exception if it is.

Comment: Thanks for testing - here is the actual data as xml https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyxlwjb9kr2hnwn/WriteLines.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping, but it turned out to be an unrelated error.

Comment: why did you post this as an answer? Please tell about the _Unrelated error_

Comment: answering stops other people from trying to solve it.  I didn't understand why it worked when it did, something to do with the lazy way this was being run.